# Selection box is dragged, but not the object

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm using FabricJS for some project, and my goal now is to save the new coordinates when the user drag an object. My issue is that when I select an object and move it, the selection box moves but not the object.
Image there:
[image: Line object and selection box not linked]

I have some code which deal with object selection and mouse click and move events, so I tried to remove them but the issue persists.

Edit: looks like it's only a graphical issue, because the object:moved event is well triggered.

Edit 2 : after some progress in the development, this bug has mutated: now the object and the selection box move together, but I have to click two times on the object to make the selection box appear (while the selection events are triggered on the first click).

Comment: use `object.setCoords()` after your operation complete.

Comment: After the operation, I clear the canvas and redraw everything (my project could be described as a limited Paint which everything is saved in an object, and interpreted to draw with Fabric).